# 22.04 USB install won't boot from USB

Tags: boot, live-usb

This is a Samsung laptop from 2012 which has no display so I can't get into the BIOS.  When I reinstall I have to dd the MBR from the hard drive to even get it to look at the USB.  20.04 boots fine and initializes the secondary monitor so I can install, 21.10 and 22.04 wont just sit there and the monitor never comes up.  What changes with the boot processes from 20.04 -> 21.10.  I'd really like to fresh install 22.04. I cant only get to 22.04 if I install 20.04, upgrade to 21.10, and then upgrade again to 22.04. Lots of time and and I am finding small little issues here and there.  Any light on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a fresh install because you need some new feature, that is missing in 20.04.4 LTS? Or do you want it because you want to test the latest and greatest, in other words because you have some extra energy to test new things?

In order to test the latest and greatest, you can also try the developing (not yet released version of Ubuntu, Kinetic Kudo, to be released as 22.10 in October.

There is a compressed image file for PC computers with 'amd64' architecture, and you can extract it directly to the internal drive of your Samsung laptop.

```
kinetic-preinstalled-server-amd64.img.xz
```

and you find the file and its sha256sum at this link:

[cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-preinstalled/20220609/](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-preinstalled/20220609/)

It needs no installation, you can extract it when running a live drive of 20.04 which boots fine, but is actually Ubuntu Server, so there is no graphical desktop environment. However, it is easy to install for example Lubuntu with the following commands

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install lubuntu-desktop
```

and after reboot you have Lubuntu :-)

You can also install `ubuntu-desktop` or the corresponding meta-package for the other community flavours of Ubuntu. I suggested Lubuntu, but can also suggest Xubuntu (`xubuntu-desktop`) because these are the most light-weight flavours, and work well in a ten year old computer.

See also the following links:

[Ubuntu Server amd64 compressed image (when extracted) boots in UEFI and BIOS mode](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692)

[Portable Lubuntu for PCs made from official Ubuntu Server compressed image file](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/portable-lubuntu-for-pcs-made-from-official-ubuntu-server-compressed-image-file/3346/2)

Comment: Wow great.  Ya just extra energy, lol.  Thanks alot for the info.  Definitely going to try that.